# How to target only X or Y value in jsonObj array

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using a method as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756997/dump-missing-date-in-data-for-chartjs) with chartJS to input dates that are missing from a JSON response.

`jsonObj["result"]["data"]` is output from the initial JSON response:

```
{
    "action": "data_link_day",
    "result": {
        "url_ending": "0",
        "data": [{
            "x": "2018-03-12",
            "y": 3
        }, {
            "x": "2018-03-16",
            "y": 5
        }]
    }
}
```

Inside the `drawChart` function, I need to separate the x/y values as graphData = y (number) and labels = x (date) by targeting them individually. I tried to do `jsonObj["result"]["data"].x` but obviously not correct.

```
  function drawChart(jsonObj) {

      var graphData = jsonObj["result"]["data"],
          labels = jsonObj["result"]["data"];

      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
          //make sure we are not checking the last date in the labels array
          if (i + 1 < labels.length) {
              var date1 = moment(labels[i], "YYYY-MM-DD");
              var date2 = moment(labels[i + 1], "YYYY-MM-DD");


              //if the current date +1 is not the same as it's next neighbor we have to add in a new one
              if (!date1.add(1, "days").isSame(date2)) {

                  //add the label
                  labels.splice(i + 1, 0, date1.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                  //add the data
                  graphData.splice(i + 1, 0, 0);
              }
          }


      }
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to separate your data into X and Y arrays:

```
let data = jsonObj.result.data;
let dataX = data.map(data => data.x);
let dataY = data.map(data => data.y);
```

Demo:

```js
const json = `
{
    "action": "data_link_day",
    "result": {
        "url_ending": "0",
        "data": [{
            "x": "2018-03-12",
            "y": 3
        }, {
            "x": "2018-03-16",
            "y": 5
        }]
    }
}`;

const input = JSON.parse(json);

let data = input.result.data;
let dataX = data.map(data => data.x);
let dataY = data.map(data => data.y);

console.log(dataX);
console.log(dataY);
```