# add current date to chartjs with momentjs

Tags: laravel, chart.js, momentjs

i need help please with this code :

[dump missing date in data for chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756997/dump-missing-date-in-data-for-chartjs)

my table for example with values:

```
bonus   date
5   : 18-04-2020
10  : 19-04-2020
0   : 20-04-2020
0   : 21-04-2020
55  : 22-04-2020
44  : 23-04-2020
30  : 24-04-2020
```

i get last 7 days date in database, chartjs display all dates, but i want in chart not to display **30  : 24-04-2020** last date but i want to display 0: 25-04-2020 if not exists in database because user not have any bonus yet today.. i think need to add 1 day in last date in chartjs ? or in database query ?

my code :

```
var graphData = [55, 10, 0, 0, 55, 44, 30],

  labels = ["18-04-2020", "19-04-2020", "20-04-2020", "21-04-2020", "22-04-2020", "23-04-2020", "24-04-2020"];



for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  //make sure we are not checking the last date in the labels array
  if (i + 1 < labels.length) {
    var date1 = moment(labels[i], "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var date2 = moment(labels[i + 1], "DD-MM-YYYY");


    //if the current date +1 is not the same as it's next neighbor we have to add in a new one
    if (!date1.add(1, "days").isSame(date2)) {

      //add the label
      labels.splice(i + 1, 0, date1.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
      //add the data
      graphData.splice(i + 1, 0, 0);
    }
  }


}


var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
    labels:labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

        data: graphData
    }]
};


var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

Comment: Please share the code that you already tried

Comment: code added, thank you.

Comment: can someone please help me ???

Comment: I can't find your `30 : 06-04-2020` you are mentioning 

Comment: what 06-04-2020 you are talking about ? i don't have this date in database.

Comment: it's in your question

Comment: sorry i mean 30  : 24-04-2020, i edited post